# Iterate over POJO properties

Tags: java, jpa

Via reflection I have found a lists of properties from x POJO classes which I need to display and also created a list of headings for which I will display the properties under(headings are from annotations on the fields).

The form of the POJO is that for each property I wish to display there is a getter.

Here are the details: The POJO's are annotated with @Entity, I am executing a query (using JPA) and getting a result set. I now want to display the result set (a collection of a particular POJO) by calling the correct getters.

I can call the getters.  My issue is having not done this... I worry that using reflection may not be particularly efficient on large result sets and perhaps there is a way to make JPA entity objects iterable in consistent way.

For instance if there an easy way to return each record as an indexable collection then I can just line up my headers in the order they would appear in each record and iterate. This then would not be a POJO but with encapsulation it could look that way in a part of the API.

Looking for suggestions! It will work one way or another but I would rather it be pretty.

Comment: When in doubt about performance, measure it!

Comment: I know it smacked of premature optimization, very premature because there isn't even a working implementation! But was more of finding a good approach.

Comment: I don't know if it is the SO way but both answers were equally valuable to me so I'll wait two days and award accepted answer to second highest up votes and 50 bounty to highest up votes, let the community break the tie for me (between esaj and Stas).

Comment: If you are using JPA 2.0, there is an included metamodel API you can leverage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867512/iterate-over-pojo-properties/4902069#4902069

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using JPA, have you tried the JPA 2 metamodel ([javax.persistence.metamodel](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/metamodel/package-summary.html)).  This will give you information about your JPA entities from the JPA metadata:

```
entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(entityClass). getAttributes();
```

Answer (score 3):

When using reflection, you do not need to necessarily invoke the getters in the objects (if the getters only return the value and don't contain any special logic), even if the fields are private (See [setAccessible](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29)).

As for performance, we are doing something similar in our current project and haven't had any problems yet (at worst, the handler checking the annotated fields on object and building JSON-data from them via reflection is traversing deeply nested object-trees (collections within collections) of up to hundreds of objects, each of which can contain from a handful to several dozen fields).

Comment: This is _very_ useful too. About read access to private fields.

Answer (score 1):

I think, itisn't good idea. Because you mix logic level with data storage level. It's better to override toString method or smt like that. If you still wanting to implement your idea, the easiest way will be to iterete throw field and access to their values by PropertyUtils

Comment: If it's just annotations on the Entities, it's not logic, just embedded metadata... the logic traversing the objects and extracting & processing the data should be elsewhere.

Comment: I've been ignoring that BeanUtils.jar for a long time now! Good to see it contains exactly what I need!

Comment: @esaj by "logic level" I mean business logic AND "view" logic. I think it should be separated from JPA.

Comment: I'll take care of it in service tier. It's a web app so (requests come into action layer, which use the service level under them which in turn access the JPA entities. The Display layer above for rendering to client is the JSPs). Because of the general nature of the reflection logic on POJO's part will probably be broken off into utility classes (not any particular tier).  Don't worry I promise to keep it clean =P

Comment: @Quaternion, Ok. But I'll be watching your project)